# Rails CSS not rendering with Heroku (already did RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

The gaps in knowledge come one after the other! (beginner aiming for 800-1000 hours of experience).

Thank you in advance for your time Stack Over Flow community.

---

**I just got my app to work on heroku, and now I have the obstacle of the CSS files not loading.**

### **Steps already taken:**

- Ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` following steps here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the_asset_pipeline
- Also manually added the important CSS files from my app/assets/stylesheets
- I also ran the following git commands:

  ```
  git add .

  git push -m "messages"

  git push heroku master
  ```

Currently, `/public/assets` has the following files:

```
8a-social-email-c07ffca4d0547e1cfad0b2b2306a715c.png
8a-social-email.png
8b-social-facebook-b440070962a72b59e40c5b5ebecf6348.png
8b-social-facebook.png
8c-social-twitter-805f23c4a7834296835aa48f14859640.png
8c-social-twitter.png
application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css
application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css.gz
application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.js
application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.js.gz
application.css
application.css.gz
application.js
application.js.gz
jquery.min-70bec01470bf6bcfed5892ae554b38c8.map
jquery.min.map
logo-img-de31fdeb33dbf84481ec3e77cee38719.png
logo-img.png
manifest.yml
normalize.css
passionportfolio.webflow.css
rails-be8732dac73d845ac5b142c8fb5f9fb0.png
rails.png
webflow.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following files and make sure they have (at least) these lines:

**`assets/stylesheets/application.css`**

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

**`config/application.rb`**

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

**`config/environments/production.rb`**

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

**`Gemfile`** (don't forget to re-run `bundle install`)

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Sources:

- [The Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)
- [Heroku Rails integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems)

Comment: Yes, they both have the lines that you mentioned above.

Comment: @dngoo Ok, can you clarify "not loading"? If you check the html source of the rendered page, can you actually see the css `link rel` tags? And if so, do they resolve to actual files?

Comment: Oh interesting... they are present but they are empty?